# Acceleration when device is on tilt

Tags: math, embedded, accelerometer, gyroscope

I'm currently working on device that uses always-on 3D accelerometer(using scale +-2g) and 3D gyroscope(using scale +-250g) -sensor.

I can read every possible vector (X,Y,Z) and their acceleration (g's) and angular rate (dps) and also the angle where the device currently is. But my problem is that when the device is on tilt (0g when no tilt) the acceleration is between (downward) 0g->-1g or between (upwards) 0g-> 1g depending on what angle the device currently is. Below is picture that hopefully clears the idea.

[image: Hopefully this helps]

The device should measure difference in acceleration (is it speeding up or slowing down). However if the device is already on tilt the accelerometer will measure some acceleration that tilt causes which makes it hard to tell if the device has truly some acceleration or is it just the tilt that causing the acceleration.

I have been thinking my head off how to eliminate that acceleration that tilt causes and only measure the real acceleration of the device but just can't think way out from this problem with the following data that i can produce.

Hopefully this message isn't too hard too understand because of my english skills and the way I'm trying to explain my problem.

Edit. The sensor also has magnetometer and can read X,Y,Z -axis if needed for the solution.

Comment: The [magnitude of the acceleration vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm) should be 1g if no other acceleration exists...

Comment: ... and direction of the vector should be downwards...

Comment: Also, you've provided both **C++** and **C** as tags, but your question contains neither

Comment: This is a maths issue.

Comment: X and Y -Axis produce 0g and the Z axis is 1g when device has no tilt and is on flat surface. The tilt causes the reading of X axis to go towards 1g if tilting is towards up and to -1g when downwards. The +-1g is reached when the device is on 90* degree from original position.

Comment: "difference in acceleration (is it speeding up or slowing down)"- no, speeding up is a difference in velocity, or acceleration (dv/dt or a, in common physical symbols). A difference in acceleration is not measured in _g_.

Comment: @MartinJames: Physics, actually. There is no math rule stating that all acceleration is indistinguishable, but this is a rule in General Relativity

Comment: Changes in acceleration are jerks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic here because it belongs on Physics.SE.

Comment: @MSalters You're right.  I will content myself with saying, then, that this problem is not a programming issue:)

Comment: Rather, it is a practical implementation problem not related to programming, math or physics. Perhaps the Electrical Engineering site would be most suitable.

Answer (score 0):

The accelerometer can't know what's up or down unless you create an external reference point. X, Y and Z are the positions relative to the accelerometer itself, not relative to the earth.

When the part is not moving you'll have 1G in *some* direction. There will be acceleration on either 1 or (more often) 2 axis. These together will give an acceleration of 1G.

To solve the problem of what is "down", you need to invent some means of calibration. You can't assume that the accelerometer is perfectly mounted. And depending on sensitivity, there are also slight local differences in gravity around the earth depending on how close to the equator you are.